# possible to launch android app via NFC with passing parameters

Tags: android, nfc

I wonder is it possible to not just simply launch an Android app (which we plan to develop ourselves allowing for that purpose) by having the NFC signal include some parameters and pass such parameters to the Android app via NFC so that, dependent on the parameter passed, e.g. a certain part of the app is accessed and/or the opening app automatically reads and saved the chips serial number?

Are such a more advanced features possible using NFC is is it limited just to "launch that app" and that's it?

THANKS A MILLION

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can define several criteria for launching the application. Once it is launched you can process in by the application code complete NDEF message.

It won't make any sense to start the application without passing the data - in such a case you will need anyway read the NFC tag or receive the NDEF over NPP/SNEP after the application will be started, so it is logical those information are already passed to the Intent.

BR
STeN

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Android Application Record. Placed it within an NDEF message, you can additionally add an External Type Record or some text-, uri-, or mimerecord depending on your needs. I have put together an [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) which should get you started.